# Why when I try to use PDO::PARAM_STR in Slim3, Slim return an error?

Tags: php, pdo, slim-3

Can somebody explain me why when I try to use `PDO::PARAM_STR` in my code, SLIM3 returns me an error ?

```
 $app->add(new \App\Middlewares\BddMiddleware($Cpdo, $Ctwig));

 class BddMiddleware {

    private $pdo;
    private $twig;

    public function __construct($pdo, $twig)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next){
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM projet WHERE name = :name');
        $query->bindParam(':name', $path, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        $projet = $query->fetch();
```

I do not understand...

This is my container :

```
$container['pdo'] = function(){
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=portfolio;host=localhost','root','', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
};
```

this doesn't work either..

```
$query->bindParam(':name', $path, $this->pdo(PDO::PARAM_STR));
```

Comment: Telling us the error is very, very important!!!

Comment: `PDO::PARAM_STR` is the default data type, so there's no reason this should be causing an error. And the reason `$this->pdo(PDO::PARAM_STR))` doesn't work is because it's calling the `pdo()` **method** of `$this`, using `PDO::PARAM_STR` as the argument. That's obviously not correct, and will produce a fatal error unless you have defined a `pdo()` method. I'm not sure where you found that syntax from. `PDO::PARAM_STR` is a constant available globally.

Comment: I wanted to add the data type to avoid injection of variable in my input. I rode that the good pratice with PDO is specify the data type when I bind the param, but no matter where I try to specify the datatype on my app (middleware or controler) slim returns me : 

"Slim Application Error
A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without exact error message, I can only guess. Make sure that you add

```
use PDO;
```

on top of `BddMiddleware` class.

To be able to view error messages, turn on Slim debug information by changing application configuration to include following values:

```
$config = [  
    'settings' => [
        ...
        'debug' => true,
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        ...
    ],
];
```

Comment: Shame on me, I actually forgot to add "use PDO" on the top of my middleware. Everything is working properly now. Thank you Zamrony, you solve my probleme